# Does windows 7 professional limit the number of cores?

Tags: windows-7, multi-processor

I have a dual processor system, each processor supporting 8 threads, so the OS should report 16 cores, which Linux does.  But Windows shows just ten of them (even the 64-bit version).  Six cores were reported as "not recognized" in the device manager. What does this mean?  Do I have to install Windows Server to use them?

Comment: Windows 7 supports between 32 and 256 cores. [Windows 7 System Requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements)

Comment: @Ramhound So something is broken?

Comment: You asked a simple question. What is the processor core limit on Windows 7 Professional. The answer is between 32 and 256 cores.  You really didn't provide enough information to diagnose the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft suggest:

> All 32-bit versions of Windows 7 can support up to 32 processor cores,
>   while 64‑bit versions can support up to 256 processor cores.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/system-requirements)

There are also a couple suggestions and workarounds for your specific problem from Microsoft found  [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/dual-core-not-recognized/220e50e2-0500-4649-b994-df2d9c985efc)

Comment: Sorry, I din't mention that I actuall have the 64-bit version installed.  As for the link you have posted: it is a dual-processor system (not dual core)

Comment: Probably a silly question, but when you go into mscongif>boot>Advanced Options. See how many cores it's using in there. By default your system should be using all the cores.

Comment: You can also go have a look how many cores are booting in Boot Configuration Data. Apologies I have no idea how to use this structure since it changed from the boot.ini. Sure a Google search will help you here.

Comment: Problem solved.  After restarting the third time, Windows now recognizes all cores.